# Can I modify the <head/> section of a Page in .NET from a User Control without runat="server"?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, metadata

I have a page that does not have runat="server" set in the `<head/>` section.  I do not have access to modify any of the code in the page.

This page contains a user control which I do have access to.  Can I add a `<meta/>` tag to the head section of the page from the user control?  It needs to be server-side so a javascript solution won't work.

Comment: If it's not marked as `runat="server"` probably not easily.  ASP.NET considers the entire section before the first control to be a single string that needs to be concatenated to generate final output.

Comment: You can always use javascript

Comment: Pass data on a hidden field and use javascript on page load to update metadata

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880138/modify-head-from-asp-net-ajax) question (and the accepted answer).  JavaScript might be the way to go.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the js solution.  Unfortunately, I can't use javascript for my particular situation.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a Response Filter, and then modify the output before it's sent to the user.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx

Comment: This is a much better approach than mine.  However, adding response filters from inside a control can quickly lead to hard to maintain code.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the text in

```
(this.Page.Controls[0] as LiteralControl).Text
```

to see where the string `<head>` starts, and insert whatever text you need in there thus injecting your own code into the page header without it being marked with `runat="server"`.

*Please be aware though, this is pretty hacky way of getting your code where it most likely shouldn't be (otherwise the `<head>` element would have been marked as `runat="server"` so you can access it normally).  This will also break if at a later date the head element is changed to be an ASP.NET control.  It might will not work with master pages, you will have to walk up the control tree looking for topmost literal element.*